# How to prevent cards from stacking on top of eachother?

Tags: html, css

I'm working on a project right now and i set a media query for when the screen is 768px it transforms into a mobile layout. Unfortunately I am having an issue with the activities section of my page. When the media query kicks in all of the cards for that section are supposed to be displayed in a flex with the direction being a column. Instead all of the cards just mash up into each other and overlap causing issues with the footer as well.

This is how that section of HTML code looks like.

```
<section class="activities" id="activities">
            <h2 class="section-title">Activites in Marseille</h2>
            <div class="cards-activities">
                <div class="grid-container">
                    <div class="card-activity gi1">
                        <a href="0">
                            <img src="images/activites/4_small/reno-laithienne-QUgJhdY5Fyk-unsplash.jpg" alt="">
                            <h4><b>Old Port</b></h4>
                        </a>
                    </div>

                    <div class="card-activity gi2">
                        <a href="0">
                            <img src="images/activites/4_small/paul-hermann-QFTrLdQIRhI-unsplash.jpg" alt="">
                            <h4><b>Pomegues Fort</b></h4>
                        </a>
                    </div>

                    <div class="card-activity gi3">
                        <a href="0">
                            <img src="images/activites/4_small/kevin-hikari-rV_Qd1l-VXg-unsplash.jpg" alt="">
                            <h4><b>Friol Island</b></h4>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="grid-container">
                    <div class="card-activity gi1">
                        <a href="0">
                            <img src="images/activites/4_small/kilyan-sockalingum-NR8-cBCN3aI-unsplash.jpg" alt="">
                            <h4><b>Calanques National Park</b></h4>
                        </a>
                    </div>

                    <div class="card-activity gi2">
                        <a href="0">
                            <img src="images/activites/4_small/florian-wehde-xW9e8gdotxI-unsplash.jpg" alt="">
                            <h4><b>Notre Dame de la Garde</b></h4>
                        </a>
                    </div>

                    <div class="card-activity gi3">
                        <a href="0">
                            <img src="images/activites/4_small/lena-paulin-wH2-EJoDcV0-unsplash.jpg" alt="">
                            <h4><b>Longchamp Park</b></h4>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

        </section>
```

This is how that section of CSS code looks like before the media query kicks in.

```
.activities {
    background-color: white;
}

.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-areas:
    'Tall Short1'
    'Tall Short2';
  grid-gap: 10px;
  background-color: white;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 0px;
  max-height: 600px;
}

.card-activity.gi1 { grid-area: Tall; }
.card-activity.gi2 { grid-area: Short1; }
.card-activity.gi3 { grid-area: Short2; }



.grid-container > div {
  background-color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 0px;
  font-size: 10px;
  min-height: 300px;
  height: 100%;
}

.cards-activities {
    display: flex;
}

.card-activity {
    border-radius: 25px;
    width: 80%;
    height: 60%;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
    transition: box-shadow 0.5s ease-in-out;
}
```

This is what the Media Query looks like.

```
@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
    .grid-container {
        border: 5px dashed red;
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        justify-content: space-between;
        margin-top: 40px;
        order: 5;
    }

    .cards-activities {
        border: 5px dashed blue;
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        margin-top: 40px;
        order: 5;
    }

    .card-activity{
        border-radius: 25px;
        width: 100%;
        box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
        transition: box-shadow 0.5s ease-in-out;
    }
}
```

[This is what the issue looks like I've put dashed borders around .cards-activities and .grid-container to investigate.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/303iF.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Trying changing your max-height from 600px to 100% in the .grid-container and tell us if that's the result that you're looking for:

```
.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-areas:
    'Tall Short1'
    'Tall Short2';
  grid-gap: 10px;
  background-color: yellow;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 0px;
  max-height: 100%;
}
```